# Sorting a set with Map.Entry values

Tags: java, sorting, set

I have a `Set` like below:

```
Set<Map.Entry<String,String>> set = new HashSet<>();
```

How can I sort this `Set` based on the key of `Map.Entry`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Tim suggested, use `TreeSet` for this purpose. But instead of defining your own `Comparator` implementation, you can just instantiate your `TreeSet` like this, using the `Comparator` already defined in the `Map.Entry` class:

```
Set<Map.Entry<String, String>> set = new TreeSet<>(Map.Entry.comparingByKey());
```

This should now give you a nicely ordered `Set`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't sort a regular Java `Set` because it is not ordered.  If you want an ordered set, one option is to use `TreeSet`.  You can create a `TreeSet` using a custom comparator, and then add your `HashSet` to it:

```
TreeSet<Map.Entry<String,String>> ts
    = new TreeSet<Map.Entry<String,String>>(new Comparator<Map.Entry<String,String>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Map.Entry<String,String> entry1, Map.Entry<String,String> entry2) {
        return entry1.getKey().compareTo(entry2.getKey());
    }
});

ts.addAll(set);
```

If you now iterate over the set, you will find that they are sorted by the keys of the `Map.Entry` elements:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : ts) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey());
}
```

Comment: The collections.sort line throws a compile time error. Am not able to figure it out.